# Eclipse Derived Resources

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

My Plugin tries to clone a mercurial repository and add some plugin specific files like
.customplugin/service.xml, .customplugin/info.xml. I dont want these files to be tracked by version control. I tried the below approach:

After creating the files, I marked them as derived. But those changes get reflected after eclipse restart.

I want the derived changes to reflect immediately. How is it possible?

Comment: Does a manual refresh of the project fix this (ie selecting it and hitting F5)? Failing that, does closing and opening the project fix it?

Comment: Why don't you ignore the files via configuration of the version control  ?

Comment: The derived attribute should be applied immediately. Do you see that when you right-click these resources? I think the problem is that versionning plugins doesn't refresh / poll this update.